# How can I archive automatically on reply in mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail

I'm using Mail with Google Apps (Gmail). My goal is to archive automatically the email I've just reply. Leaving me with a clean inbox. How can you that exactly? (I'm using MailTags and Mail Act-On a lot.)

Answer (score 4):

The option I use to to have [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) intercept the standard send button key command, and then run a macro that

1. Sends the message.
2. Moves the message to my archive folder.

I set the macro for the standard Shift-Control-D. Keyboard Maestro intercepts that key command. It then executes the rule "Select 'Send' in the menu 'Message' in Mail", and then "Select 'Archive' in the menu 'Message' in Mail". Archive is the name of my folder. So Keyboard Maestro is just executing those commands in the menu, since there isn't any build-in keystroke for moving messages to folders in Mail.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, Jon! Thanks for posting an answer! Can you please add more information? For instance, how do you set the macro and what keystrokes/commands do you record? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Sure. I set the macro for the standard Shift-Control-D. Keyboard Maestro intercepts that key command. It then executes the rule "Select 'Send' in the menu 'Message' in Mail", and then "Select 'Archive' in the menu 'Message' in Mail". Archive is the name of my folder. So Keyboard Maestro is just executing those commands in the menu, since there isn't any build-in keystroke for moving messages to folders in Mail.

Comment: Awesome! Can you please add them to your answer by clicking the "edit" button? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Apple's Mail.app doesnt have a feature to toggle for this, but you /can/ do this in Sparrow.

[Sparrow](http://sparrowmailapp.com/) has a lite version that might suit your needs, but the full version does what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [MailHub](http://dervishsoftware.com/) better than (or in combination with) Act-On is the winner.